# Where is bash initial environment variable set on MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

Upon open a bash on my OS X terminal, there was an environment variable `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` already set, but that did not come from any `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. I'd like to know who (which script) set that environment variable. Is there a good way to check?

Comment: there's also system-wide rc files, the system boot scripts, etc...

Comment: Not necessarily set by bash at all, but often by the programs elsewhere in your operating system that themselves *start* bash. Programs inherit environment variables from their parent processes; this is as true of bash as of anything else.

Comment: In MacOS, for instance, `/etc/launchd.conf` can have global environment variables. There's also `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`. This is much more a MacOS question than a bash question, and it would perhaps be better placed on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow, or on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) with MacOS-specific tagging.

Comment: ...on your more Linux-y operating systems, user-session environment variables are often set by PAM modules (which themselves, like launchd, are executed before bash is ever started, making this in no way bash-specific). It's a very system-dependent question; I've amended title and tagging appropriately.